# can we use @around method in filter class?

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop, restful-authentication

I have my authentication class where i want to fetch something which require EntityManager which is present in a class. That class only works after authentication is done.

I have tried importing bean of that class in authentication class. Then i tried initializing EntityManager in Authentication class. But i didn't the things i wanted from that class. I looked over AOP and come to know about @Around annotation, which require to have "ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint" in method argument. But as i have implemented Filter class in Authentication class, i can't override my filter class. Can we have some work around for that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Where is your code? Please kindly provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I cannot compile and debug your ambiguous prose. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AOP, The method you need to annotate with `@Around` is not the method you want to wrap, but the method you want to be called 'around' it (the aspect method). The `joinPoint` parameter in the method is there to represent your 'wrapped' method, and there to tell it when to execute it.

I think an example will be best to understand.
Consider this simple AOP method that prints 'before' and 'after' the execution:

This is the aspect class

```
@Around("execution(* testWrappedMethod(..))")
public void aopSample(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
  System.out.println("before"); 
  joinPoint.proceed();// this will make the wrapped method execute
  System.out.println("after");
}
```

and this is the 'wrapped' method:

```
public void testWrappedMethod(String whatever) {
  System.out.println("inside");
}
```

The output of the execution of `testWrappedMethod` will be:

> before
>   inside
>   after

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i have one more question over here, can we have something like setting a variable present in testWrappedmethod in aopSample method using the same?